# html5 validate same pattern in different inputs

Tags: regex, html, validation

I've been trying to find a more effective way validate inputs with html5. I have several inputs with the same pattern and so far I've copied an pastad the same pattern in each input.

E.G.:

```
<input type="text" id="foo1" name="bar1" pattern="([a-z]{2}[0-9]{2})"/>
<input type="text" id="foo2" name="bar2" pattern="([a-z]{2}[0-9]{2})"/>
<input type="text" id="foo3" name="bar3" pattern="([a-z]{2}[0-9]{2})"/>
...
<input type="text" id="fooN" name="barN" pattern="([a-z]{2}[0-9]{2})"/>
```

I want to do it in such a way that I only have the pattern in one place.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with plain html5 but you could use JavaScript or jQuery for that:

**JavaScript**:

```
<script>
    var input_fields = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i = 0; i < input_fields.length; i++) {
        if(input_fields[i].type.toLowerCase() == 'text') {
            input_fields[i].setAttribute('pattern', '([a-z]{2}[0-9]{2})');
        }
    }
</script>
```

**jQuery**:

```
<script>
    $('text').attr('pattern', '([a-z]{2}[0-9]{2})');
</script>
```